# Is there a way I can check which block of disk is really used?

Tags: centos, disk-space, disk-utility, du, df

I use **df** and **du** to check disk usage of centos,then I get different results from these tools.

`[root@localhost home]# df -Th
Filesystem          Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/cl-root xfs       149G   31G  119G  21% /
devtmpfs            devtmpfs   32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs               tmpfs      32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               tmpfs      32G   41M   32G   1% /run
tmpfs               tmpfs      32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda1           xfs      1014M  178M  837M  18% /boot
tmpfs               tmpfs     6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs               tmpfs     6.3G   16K  6.3G   1% /run/user/1001
[root@localhost /]# du -sh / 2>/dev/null
7.0G    /`

However, I've rebooted the system several times and make sure that there is no big file deleted and recalculated.

This problem is really confused me for tow days,so I want to know if there is any way I can find out which blocks of disk is used? If yes,I can get where the missed 23.3Gs gone ?

`[root@localhost home]# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
vda         252:0    0   150G  0 disk 
├─vda1      252:1    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─vda2      252:2    0   149G  0 part 
  ├─cl-root 253:0    0 148.6G  0 lvm  /
  └─cl-swap 253:1    0   412M  0 lvm  [SWAP]`

Comment: What filesystem? Please [edit] the question (provide output of `mount` maybe). Example: I mount a certain subvolume of Btrfs on `/`. `du` works on file level and sees only this subvolume. There are other subvolumes that take space and `df` reflects this.

Comment: Related: [How to analyse disk usage in command line Linux?](https://superuser.com/q/300606/150988), [du vs df output](https://superuser.com/q/289678/150988), [Linux filesystem; difference in calculating size using df & du](https://superuser.com/q/304391/150988), [Difference between "df -k" and "du -sh"](https://superuser.com/q/279497/150988), and [Discrepancy between df and du](https://superuser.com/q/581496/150988).

Answer (score 0):

After cleaned up disk fragmentation with xfs_fsr,the missing disk space came back!

`[root@localhost /]# xfs_db -c frag -r /dev/mapper/cl-root 
actual 430606, ideal 421725, fragmentation factor 2.06%
Note, this number is largely meaningless.
Files on this filesystem average 1.02 extents per file
[root@localhost /]# xfs_fsr /dev/mapper/cl-root 
/ start inode=0
[root@localhost /]# xfs_db -c frag -r /dev/mapper/cl-root 
actual 428060, ideal 421496, fragmentation factor 1.53%
Note, this number is largely meaningless.
Files on this filesystem average 1.02 extents per file
[root@localhost /]# df -h
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/cl-root 149G 7.0G 142G 5% /
devtmpfs 32G 0 32G 0% /dev
tmpfs 32G 0 32G 0% /dev/shm
tmpfs 32G 41M 32G 1% /run
tmpfs 32G 0 32G 0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda1 1014M 178M 837M 18% /boot
tmpfs 6.3G 0 6.3G 0% /run/user/1000
[root@localhost /]# du -sh
6.8G .
[root@localhost /]#`